# LightFM: Weights and Sample Weights

Tags: recommendation-engine

I was looking to gain insight on the weights for the LightFM Implementation for the following:

#### Sample Weights

- What are `sample_weights` in the `fit` method? I read that they are to simulate time decay but how does that work exactly? Examples or an article explaining this would be really helpful.

#### Interactions Matrix

- now if I have user interactions with different `content_type`s i.e. `text`, `video` and we don't want to really differentiate between them when we make a recommendation?

  - Do I have to make separate models for each media type? If I create one model, does it make a difference if the interactions for `text` is a boolean like 1.0/0.0 for clicks and if the interactions for `video` is in `percentage_video_completed` e.g. if a user sees 10 seconds out of a 15 second video, can I assign an weight as 0.667?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Sample weights

You can use `sample_weights` to weigh the importance of any one observation, in the same way you can pass `sample_weight` to an sklearn [classifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.partial_fit).

Weights larger than 1 will lend additional weight to that observation; weights smaller than one will make it less important to the model.

This is accomplished by scaling the learning rate for that observation by its weight.

#### Interactions

You don't have to create separate models: the two types of interactions can happily be embedded in the same model.

In LightFM models, the data in the interactions matrix is binary. You should use the sample weights to express the confidence you have that a given interaction is positive. This can be percentage watched for movies: however, be aware that if percentage watched is routinely under 1.0, your model will put more weight on the text interactions.

Comment: Thanks. So, just to confirm my understanding, if I'm just considering text interactions and if the interactions are binary, then if I start using the frequency of interactions e.g. no. of clicks, e.g. a person will have 10 for an article he likes a lot and 1 for another, then it won't make a difference in this binary matrix, both will be considered the same?

Comment: This is correct. If you want to take the number of clicks into account, you should use the weights matrix (but be careful with very large weights, these can affect the stability of the fitting).